# Why my ID is undefined and why i can't modify the css properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why my ID startButton is undefined in my code .
The problem is that i can't modify the CSS of startButton ... :'(
Can you please help me ?

```
        if(this.pauseButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        clearInterval(idIntervale);


        const box = document.getElementById("playPause");
        this.startButton.setAttribute("id", "startButton");
        this.startButton.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-play'></i>"
        box.replaceChild(this.startButton, this.pauseButton);

    }));
```

here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="playPause">
<div id="pauseButton"> <i class="fas fa-pause"></i></div>
<div id="startButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with the code??

Comment: where you define the `this.startButton`?

Comment: You should refer to the DOM elements with `document.getElementById(ID_HERE)`, elements don't have arbitrary elements as their properties. Also, I doubt `this` in your event handler is not what you think it is.

Comment: this.startButton = document.createElement(startButton); // create play button

Comment: again, could you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bgr4f9y1/1/

Comment: the problem is that i don't understand why the ID startButton create in my JS files is undefined  . 

i would like that it appear as a DIV in my html

Comment: Your code instantiates a `new Slider()` but you didn't specify a parameter for the `startButton`'s selector, could that be the cause? Side note: don't use `<div>`. You even called them `…Button`. Use a `<button>`. Your users will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure on what you mean but I think I get the rough idea:
Try accessing it this way:

```
let playPause = document.body.querySelector("#playPause");
let startBtn = playPause.getElementById("startButton");
startButton.style.color = red; //or whatever style you want to do.
```

What I think, is that you couldn't access it before because it wasn't a direct child of the body, but of `#playPause`.
Hope this works!

Comment: It is style undefined but now i can modify the CSS property  . 

Thanks a lot everybody !